# PHP e Javascript - Mostrar alerta sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, button, alert

Possuo na minha página um botão que faz envio de e-mail com algumas informações preenchidas. Contudo, se dois dos campos estiverem vazios, o browser dá um aviso de alerta (indicado no código abaixo no TODO).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnEnvia'])){
    $unidade        = $_POST['unidade'];
    $solicitante    = $_POST['solicitante'];

    $campanha       = str_replace("chkCamp","Campanha ",$_POST['campanhaNome_enviar']);
    $layout         = str_replace("chkCamp","img",$_POST['campanhaNome_enviar']);

    $qtdBanner      = $_POST['qtdBanner'];
    $qtdCartaz      = $_POST['qtdCartaz'];
    $qtdOutdoor     = $_POST['qtdOutdoor'];
    $qtdFlyer       = $_POST['qtdFlyer'];
    $qtdEmail       = $_POST['qtdEmail'];

    $texto1         = $_POST['texto1'];

    // TODO Este alerta está fazendo refresh na página!!!
    if(($solicitante == "") or ($texto1 == "")){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('Há campos não preenchidos!');
        </script>";
        return false;
    }
    else{

    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.meuservidor.com.br'; // SMTP servers
    $mail->Port = 25; // SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'autenticacao@meuservidor.com.br'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'senha@123'; // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'autenticacao@meuservidor.com.br';
    $mail->FromName = $solicitante;
    $mail->AddAddress('meuemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Solicitação de Material de Marketing - Unidade ' . $unidade;

    // corpo da mensagem
    $mail->Body = '<html>
        <body>
            <div style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px;">
                <div style="text-align: center; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px;"><img src="http://minhaurl.png"></img><br><br>Solicitação de material de Marketing:</div>
                <br><br>Unidade: '.$unidade.'
                <br>Solicitante: '.$solicitante.'
                <br><br>Campanha Escolhida: '.$campanha.'
                <br><br><img src="minhaurl.png">
                <br><br>Briefing: '.$texto1.'
                <br><br>Material:
                <br>* Banner: '.$qtdBanner.'
                <br>* Cartaz: '.$qtdCartaz.'
                <br>* Outdoor: '.$qtdOutdoor.'
                <br>* Flyer: '.$qtdFlyer.'
                <br>* E-mail: '.$qtdEmail.'
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>';

    // corpo da mensagem em modo texto
    $mail->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto';

    // verifica se enviou corretamente
    if ( $mail->Send() ) {
        echo "<script>
            alert('Pedido enviado!');
        </script>";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Erro do PHPMailer: ' . $Mailer->ErrorInfo;
    }
    }
}
```

Código do botão btnEnvia:

```
<input name="btnEnvia" type="submit" value="Enviar" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 20px" /><
```

O problema é que, nesse meu caso, a página é atualizada automaticamente e depois aparece o alerta. E nesse refresh, ele perde o que eu já preenchi de dados, voltando do início.

Como eu poderia fazer pra que não aconteça esse refresh e me dê o alerta sem problemas?

Comment: em vez de type=submit troque para button

Comment: Outra dica é não exibir conteúdo sensível do seu negócio no exemplo.
Digamos s credenciais de conexão do smtp da intercity hoteis.
Mas se forem fake. Ok.

Comment: Não deu certo, @Marconi. Aí o botão não funciona de forma nenhuma.

Comment: JQuery é uma opção pra você? Ou prefere javascript "puro"?

Comment: @GustavoHoppeLevin Não funciona ou não submete o formulario?

Comment: @Moykn Pode ser os dois. O que sugere?

Comment: @Marconi Não submete

Comment: Você pode fazer a validação com esse tipo de botão, e usar o submit do jquery para submeter o seu formulario. https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer enviar as informações do formulário e manter o que digitou depois do alert, O seu botão é PHP, ele envia as informações da página (Cliente) para o servidor e devolve uma página HTML como resultado, em PHP é possível guardar as informações em uma variavel $_POST ou $_GET e depois setar os dados na página resultado no lado do servidor. Ou pode usar o Java para isto, neste caso NÃO usará o botão submit para enviar informações para o servidor.

Comment: Cara, que tosco isso, enviar um `alert()` além de ser desagradável para o usuário, ele nem sabe quais são os dois campos com valor vazio. Eu acho que você deveria rever seu formulário, pois há vários problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Usando jQuery.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
        if($("#solicitante").val()==="" || $("#texto1").val()===""){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Preencha todos os campos");                
        }
});
```

Chamar o e.preventDefault(); Evita que o submit seja executado, assim evitando o post.

Comment: +1 boa resposta, tinha me esqueçido do preventDefault.

Comment: Tranquilo. Acabamos esquecendo. Faz tempo que não uso código assim. :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o que o Moykn sugeriu ou então trocar o `type='submit'` para `type='button'`

A única diferença é que trocando o submit por button, em seu código PHP, isso não funcionará mais: `if(isset($_POST['btnEnvia'])){`

Você pode trocar o isset do btnEnvia para qualquer 1 dos campos do seu formulário.

Ah, é claro que também trocando o submit para button, você precisa utilizar o JS para enviar o formulário.

Enfim...há várias possibilidades.